# Java SSL Certificate

Tags: java, security, ssl

I need to communicate between two desktop Java app, and the best way to do this is to use SSL (to prevent sniffers). I control both the client and server so self-signed is okay.

My question is if a certificate can be made and used from scratch programmatically (i.e. the end user does not have to physically do anything himself).

If this is possible, could you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is if a certificate can be made and used from scratch
> programmatically (i.e. the end user does not have to physically do
> anything himself).

Before you think of generating certificates (programmatically or not), you need to decide how you're going to verify them. In the context of two desktop applications, the traditional way of verifying a server certificate might not be suitable.

The purpose of the certificates is to give a way to verify the identity of the remote party, so as to prevent Man-In-The-Middle attacks. The verifying party uses something it already trusts to make this verification; not doing so makes using certificates pointless.

In the traditional model (with a fixed server), the server certificate is part of a PKI and issued by a CA. The client verifies its authenticity against a set of CA certificates it trusts (typically using the rules described in [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), and it verifies the certificate is valid for the host name is was looking for (how this is done depends on the protocol, but best and historical practices are described in [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)). Both steps are necessary to prevent MITM attacks. It's similar to verifying someone's identity using a passport: you want to check that the passport is real and from an authority you trust, and you want to check that the name (or picture) matches the name you're looking for (or the face in front of you).

When establishing a communication between two desktop applications, you're certainly going to have problems with both aspects: how to let the client verify the cert was issued by an entity you trust, and was issued to the entity you want to communicate with. If you generate the certificate programmatically no either side, it's certainly going to be self-signed, which will make verifying its authenticity from the other side difficult without another means of exchange (independent of this SSL/TLS communication). In addition, desktops tend not to have fixed host names, so a DNS-based (or even an IP address) identifier might be inadequate in this context.

You'll need to think of a way to publish the certificate in a way that the remote party can verify it trusts it, and to think of an identifying scheme to make sure the certificate belongs to the right entity (this is typically what goes in the Subject DN or Subject Alternative Name extension of the certificate).

Once you've made these decisions, you can use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)'s `org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator` to generate your certificate (an X.509 v3 certificate should let you add extensions to the certificate, e.g. for key usage purpose, if you need them). There are various examples (for v1, v3 and/or self-signed, i.e. where Subject = Issuer) on the [BouncyCastle wiki](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation). I'd say that using this is the easy bit unfortunately (the administrative side of trust would be the hardest).

If both desktop applications are in fact both part of a more central application, you could run a service that issues this certificate, from a certificate request (CSR) generated within your application. A central server would effectively run your own CA, and your desktop applications would trust that CA. Depending on the complexity of your organisation, there are tools available to do this, or you could also use BouncyCastle to implement it, using the same classes (it would even be better if you implemented CRL/OSCP to be able to revoke certificates). In this case, you could make your application generate a CSR and submit it to your central CA. CSRs can be generated with BouncyCastle using `PKCS10CertificationRequest`. Again, how your CA verify the CSR comes from the right party, using external information, is also an administrative problem, perhaps you can tie it to an e-mail verification scheme or something like that.

Once you've generated your certificates, you'll be able to use [Java's JSSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) as your SSL/TLS stack (typically using `SSLSocket`). You may have to use custom `X509TrustManager`s to implement the certificate verification (depending on how you've designed your scheme to verify the certificate, if you're unable to use a traditional CA model). Just make sure you don't use trust managers that don't do anything in their `check*` methods; there are a number of examples of this around: you might as well not use certificates at all in this case, if you don't do anything to verify them (this would make the connections vulnerable to MITM attacks).

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed explanation! My intent is to generate a certificate on the `admin` instance of my app and then distribute a copy of the app with the trusted certificate to `judges`. This way I know exactly which certificate to trust.

Comment: If you only have one instance of your "admin" app, perhaps it's not worth having some code to generate the certificate (`keytool` can be used to generate self-signed certs).

Comment: Well, the `admin` is going to be a user who may or may not have JDK installed in his or her computer.

Comment: As far as I know, `keytool` comes with the JRE, which you'll certainly need to run a Java application. Doing it within your application may be a matter of convenience for your users.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JCE based solution with [SSLSocket, docs for jdk6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) and its implementation: SSLSocketImpl.

Java SSL SSH:

You have [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) lib to connect to any server with SSH protocol.

Java Toolbox for SSL:

You have [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org). 
Look at their [resources](http://www.bouncycastle.org/resources.html) and their [documentation](http://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html). The wiki provides [some usefull examples](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/BC+Version+2+APIs) with the latest releases:

```
ContentSigner sigGen = ...;
PublicKey publicKey = ....;

Date startDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
Date endDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

X509v1CertificateBuilder v1CertGen = new JcaX509v1CertificateBuilder(
          new X500Principal("CN=Test"), 
          BigInteger.ONE, 
          startDate, endDate, 
          new X500Principal("CN=Test"), 
          publicKey);

X509CertificateHolder certHolder = v1CertGen.build(sigGen);
```

Comment: "*Java SSL SSH*": just to point out that SSH has nothing to do with SSL. (You also probably meant JSSE, not JCE.)

Comment: Of course, but if you need to interact with your server using SSH+SSL, then Jsch is a very good library... If you look at the Bouncy Castle example, it builds a certificate you could use as you need.

Comment: I'm not sure under which circumstances you'd need both SSH+SSL, though.

Comment: When you have a certificate for a server, it could become very handy to interact via SSH in order to install some services and programs on the server via SSH, which uses internally SSL to secure the connection. Or maybe I'm wrong? lol! These use case is because you are a human being, not always in front of your dedicated server to look the result of a very long installation process. A process which could be automated of course.

Comment: "*SSH, which uses internally SSL to secure the connection*", yes that's the bit where you're wrong. SSH (RFC 4253 and related) is a completely different protocol from SSL/TLS (you won't find any occurrences of the word "TLS" in that spec). OpenSSH uses the OpenSSL library for its lower-level routines, not for its SSL/TLS stack (OpenSSL does far more than SSL/TLS). In addition, the vast majority of SSH servers don't use certificates, but plain RSA/DSA keys (there are some OpenSSH patches for X.509 certs or GSI, but they're not so widely used).

Comment: Ok, glad to have learn something today :D
I use OpenSSL to generate certificates on some dedicated servers, very good tool :)